# After cloning my WordPress database to another server, I cannot log in

Tags: multisite, migration, authentication

I'm in the process of creating a new upgraded staging server to replace our current one. The domain name will change. I'd like to make the switch-over seamless, meaning users can continue to log in with their current credentials.

The new server looks operational. I can see the front page with posts displayed. But when I try to log in, I get the message:

> ERROR: The password you entered for your username is incorrect.

Additional facts:

- The database is cloned using a script that clones data from a production server to staging. This script has been used without issue with the old staging server.
- The clone script does run `wp search-replace --network --recurse-objects --url`.
- The sites (production, old staging, new staging) all use single sign-on with the [AD Integration plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/active-directory-integration).
- If I change my user password in the new database using `wp-cli`, I can log in. (This not a solution because I cannot require all users to change their passwords.)
- I have looked up my user password in both the old and new databases and they match:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = 'foobar';
  | ID  | user_login | user_pass    |
  | 166 | foobar     | $P$BE ... g1 |
  ```
- Suspecting maybe it has something to do with a salt or a nonce, I copied the `wp-security-keys.php` file from the old staging server to the new one.
- Tried logging in in incognito window to rule out stale cookies or cache.
- It is a network / MU site.

I strongly suspect it has something to do with the encryption/decryption of the password. But nothing I've tried thus far has fixed it. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to reset your password? I mean "Lost your password?" link.

Comment: @MaxYudin One goal of this migration is to allow users to continue to login with their current passwords. So I expect using the "Lost your password" link would work. But this doesn't solve my problem. I'll edit question to clarify this.

Comment: Are the sites 100% identical code-wise? Anything else changed? PHP, MySQL,...?

Comment: did you look up your password before or after changing it using wp-cli?

Comment: @kraftner Upgraded PHP from 5.3.3 to 7.1.4. Points to the same MySQL server. Webserver switched from nginx to Apache. Source code unchanged.

Comment: @inarilo The password change was done just to confirm that login was authenticating against WP database (vs, say, LDAP service). The database was recloned before lookup -- so, in effect, password was not changed.